# jQuery width() and height() return 0 for img element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am creating a new image element once I get response from AJAX call with image metadata like this:

```
var loadedImageContainter = $('<div class="loaded-image-container"></div>');
var image = $('<img src="' + file.url + '" alt="">');
loadedImageContainter.append(image);
$('.loading-image').replaceWith(loadedImageContainter);
var width = image.width();
var height = image.height();
console.log(width);
console.log(height);
```

But width() and height() functions are returning 0 although image has 30 x 30 px size and it appears correctly on the page. I need to get its dimensions in order to absolutely position the image.

Comment: Try $(window).load(function(){
var width = image.width();
var height = image.height();
console.log(width);
console.log(height);
});

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to wait until the image has loaded to have access to the width and height data.

```
var $img = $('<img>');

$img.on('load', function(){
  console.log($(this).width());
});

$img.attr('src', file.url);
```

Or with plain JS:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');

img.onload = function(){
  console.log(this.width);
}

img.src = file.url;
```

Also, you don't need to insert the image into the DOM before you read the width and height values, so you could leave your `.loading-image` replacement until after you calculate all of the correct positions.

Comment: The jQuery code here is not working for me but the plain is, at least in Chrome v51.0.2704 using jQuery 1.12.4. It should work though. console.log($(this).width()); logs 0 no matter what, may be something strange in the width method's implementation. Accessing the width property works though console.log($(this)[0].width); or if you want to use jQuery: console.log($(this).prop("width"));

Comment: @StephenBrown I'm also getting 0 no matter what if I try to use $(this).width();

Comment: I found that the load event was not always getting fired when reloading the page over and over with a combination of Control-R and Control-F5. I suspect this is because I'm iterating over a set of images in a jQuery DOM array so I have to first wait for the document.ready event to fire which could be after the image has loaded. To get around this I added a check for whether width/height are 0 and only wait for the onload event if they are.

Answer (score 8):

That is because your image isn't loaded when you check width

Try using load event this way

```
$('img').on('load',function(){
  // check width
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As @ahren [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16084408/1821692) earlier the reason is that image not loaded when you tring to get it's sizes.

If you want to fix this without jQuery you can use vanilla JS `addEventListener` method:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].addEventListener('load', function() {
    // ...
    var width = image.width();
    var height = image.height();
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the alternate API [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$('<img src="' + file.url + '" alt="">').load( function(){ <your function implementation> });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it only works with "appendTo"

```
$('<img src="myImage.jpeg">').load(function(){
   $w = $(this).width(); 
   $h = $(this).height();
   $(this).remove()
}).appendTo("body")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('.loading-image').replaceWith(loadedImageContainter);
$('.loading-image').load(function(){
    var width = image.width();
    var height = image.height();
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

If you put it inside the AJAX call, that will work too, this is for json method

```
$.post("URL",{someVar:someVar},function(data){

   var totalImgs = $('body').find('img').length;

   var image = $('<img src="' + data.file[0].url + '" alt="" id="IMG_'+ totalImgs +'">');

   loadedImageContainter.append(image);
   $('.loading-image').replaceWith(loadedImageContainter);

   var width = $('#IMG_'+totalImgs).width();
   var height = $('#IMG_'+totalImgs).height();

},'json');
```