# Get the Height of an Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This should be easy but it's not.  I just need the height of an image:

```
<div id="map">
    <img src="myimage.jpg">
</div>
```

```js
$("#map img").height(); // returns 0
```

Comment: Add  _complete_ code, when you are trying to get the image height

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084374/jquery-width-and-height-return-0-for-img-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Comment: `This should be easy but it's not` really? :P http://stackoverflow.com/a/623174/3681882

Answer (score 2):

Use `.clientHeight` (pure JavaScript):

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/v6yz8t3u/

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('img').clientHeight);
```

```html
<img src="//makelin.us/100/100" />
```

Read up on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight

Note that this will give you the height as the image appears on the page, it could be affected by CSS.

**Note:** To get the actual height of the image, use `.naturalHeight`.
**Great article here:** https://davidwalsh.name/get-image-dimensions

To make sure this runs after the image has loaded, do:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  console.log(document.querySelector('img').clientHeight);
});
```

Comment: Consider reading this answer- http://stackoverflow.com/a/623174/3681882
According to you, does this return the _actual_ image height or the _rendered_ height?

Comment: @CrakC, thanks for the ping. It is the rendered height, I added `.naturalHeight` in as well.

Comment: The problem is that the image dimensions has not yet been loaded, see my answer below.

Comment: Added load listener (although the JS should be near end of `<body>`).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the height or width are not calculated yet, listen to the loading of the image with [.on( "load", handler )](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```js
$("#map img").on("load", function(){
  var height = $(this).height();
  $('#output').html('height=' + height);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x40">
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Likely true but already posted about half an hour earlier in the comments. By the way, `load()` used like this has been deprecated for a while. This is the correct link : http://api.jquery.com/load-event/.

Comment: Seems like since 1.8, you are right. But substitute with `.on( "load", handler )` should be ok, right?

Comment: Basically yes but I think there's a bit more to it than that. If the image has been cached, the load event will not fire - and neither will the height calculation in that case. So a broader approach might be to listen for the `window` onload event (which will always be correct) or do a check beforehand using `.complete` which is the indicator for the image being loaded already. But that last bit would just be needed if one would like to save some time and might overcomplicate things. The accepted answer in the link that was upvoted in the comments isn't really treating this correctly either.

Comment: Ahh yes, window onload event is better in this scenario. :)

Comment: I used window onload and it still didn't work.   All the images come back with 0 height.  It must be because they are cached?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following example to get height of image-

```
<div id="map">
    <img id="img_id" src="http://www.clickerzoneuk.co.uk/cz/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/PuppySmall.jpg" >
</div>
```

write following code in js file

```
var height = document.getElementById("img_id").clientHeight;

alert(height);
```

check example using following link-

http://jsfiddle.net/v60mut3L/1/

Comment: `.height` is obsolete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/height

Comment: If I console.log the object, there is a 'height' property.  That's a jQuery thing right?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var artLists = [];
    $("ul.articles").each(function (index) {
        var imageHts = [];
        $("li img", $(this)).each(function () {
            imageHts.push($(this)[0].height);
        })
        artLists.push(imageHts);
    })

});
```